# Making UITableView with delete buttons visible for all cells

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Normally one can create a UITableView with cells that allow the user to reveal the red "Delete" button on the right side of the cell by swiping that cell or by tapping a knob visible on the left side of the cell.

However, I would like to create a UITableView which has all cells with visible "Delete" button by default (no swiping / tapping knob necessary). Is it possible to do utilizing the standard Cocoa Touch methods?

(I know I can define my own button in a custom UITableViewCell, but I'd rather use a standard method if possible...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. NO. Actually the red minus on the left side is the constant-visible solution in Cocoa. I don't believe you get the right delete button without ugly hacking of the tableView.

So probably you have to make a custom solution. But you need no subclassing here. You can just use a regular UITableViewCell and set a `UIButton` as the `accessoryView`.

Comment: Accepted, my apologies for the delay :).

Answer (score 2):

Call `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO]` in your view controller's `-viewDidLoad` implementation.

Comment: Doing so enables swipe behavior in all cells (shows delete button only after swipe gesture on the cell). I was asking about showing delete buttons on all cells without need for a user to swipe / tap knob.